# How can I append a Series to an existing DataFrame row with pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, append, series

I want to take a series and append it to an existing dataframe row. For example:

```
df

   A  B  C
0  2  3  4
1  5  6  7
2  7  8  9

series

0 x 
1 y
2 z

-->

   A  B  C D E F
0  2  3  4 x y z
1  5  6  7 ...
2  7  8  9 ...
```

I want to do this using a for loop, appending a different series to each row of the dataframe. The series may have different lengths. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you provide more than one series to the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Use `loc` and the series's index as the column name

```
lst = [
    [2,3,4],
    [5,6,7],
    [7,8,9]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=list("ABC"))
print(df)
### 
   A  B  C
0  2  3  4
1  5  6  7
2  7  8  9

s1 = pd.Series(list("xyz"))
s1.index = list("DEF")
print(s1)
###
D    x
E    y
F    z
dtype: object

s2 = pd.Series(list("abcd"))
s2.index = list("GHIJ")
print(s2)
###
G    a
H    b
I    c
J    d
dtype: object

for idx, s in enumerate([s1, s2]):
    df.loc[idx, s.index] = s.values

print(df)
### 
   A  B  C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J
0  2  3  4    x    y    z  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  5  6  7  NaN  NaN  NaN    a    b    c    d
2  7  8  9  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['D'], df['E'], df['F'] = s.tolist()
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Gives:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  2  3  4  x  y  z
1  5  6  7  x  y  z
2  7  8  9  x  y  z
```

**Edit:**

If you are not sure how many extra values there are, try:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as letters
df = df.assign(**dict(zip([letters[i + len(df.columns)] for i, v in enumerate(series)], series.tolist())))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  2  3  4  x  y  z
1  5  6  7  x  y  z
2  7  8  9  x  y  z
```

Comment: this does not really work for my needs, as I do not know the number of new columns needed beforehand

Comment: @scottdun5 Edietd my answer please check it out